# Limit the number of products displayed in woocommerce product category pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I am using the sober theme and I want to limit number of products to be show on the category page of each category.

Currently it is showing more than 10 products on a single page, what if I want to limit this to 10? I was able to limit number of related products on products description page.

How do I limit number of products on the category page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the number of items per page for woocommerce product category archives pages, you will use:

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'items_per_page_in_product_category_archives', 900 );
function items_per_page_in_product_category_archives( $limit ) {
    if( is_product_category() )
        $limit = 10;

    return $limit;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, What should I do, If I have a load more button at the bottom of every page. Is there any inbuilt function to get category products or do I need to write a custom query.

Comment: For the load more button, that is specific to your theme as by default there is pagination… The product category archives pages can be accessed also from the woocommerce widget product category (that you can add in the side bar) or from any product page in its linked product category terms.